# Creating elements and event listeners with a for loop

Tags: javascript, dom, for-loop

I have an array of objects and I have defined a function to reference this objects using the this keyword.

```
var catArray = [toodles, whiskers, cornelius, poko, flufflepuss];

function catClicker() {
  currentCat.textContent = this.name;
  photo.src = this.src;
  console.log("clicked on " + this.name);
  catNow = this;
  clicker.textContent = this.clicks;
}
```

I am trying to add list items to a html ul using a for loop and add event listeners for my function at the same time. Why is it not working?

```
for (var i = 0; i < catArray.length; i++) {
  var item = document.createElement('li');
  item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(catArray[i].name));
  item.addEventListener("click", catClicker); 
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors? The code (as posted) would result in errors should that handler actually be called; `currentCat`, `photo`, `catNow`, and `clicker` aren't defined.

Comment: I haven't post all my code just the part that is problematic

Comment: Are you putting the new elements you create into the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to set the correct `this` scope.

```
item.addEventListener('click', catClicker.bind(catArray[i]));
```

Comment: Are you sure? `this` should be set to the element by the event listening mechanism.

Comment: @torazaburo [Positive](https://jsfiddle.net/p4L7aoe1/). This sets `this` to the object in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I have this working maybe you can work out what was wrong with your code from this. It is hard for me to tell what your problem is because vital bits of the code is missing from what you have posted.

```
function whenReady(){
  for (var i = 0; i < catArray.length; i++) {
  var item = document.createElement('li');
  var d
  item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(catArray[i].name));
  item.attributes.setNamedItem(
    (d=document.createAttribute('data-catArray-idx'),d.value=i,d)
  )
  document.body.appendChild(item)
  item.addEventListener("click", catClicker);
  catClicks.set(catArray[i],{clicks:0})
  }
  catView=CatView().setCat(catArray[0]).appendToElement(document.body)
}

var catView
var catClicks=new WeakMap()
var catArray = [
  {name: "toodles",url:"images/toodles.jpg",height:100,width:150},
  {name: "whiskers",url:"images/whiskers.jpg",height:100,width:150},
  {name: "cornelius",url:"images/cornelius.jpg",height:100,width:150},
  {name: "poko", url:"images/poko.jpg",height:100,width:150},
  {name: "flufflepuss",url:"images/flufflepuss.jpg",height:100,width:150}
]

var clicks=0
function catClicker() {
  catView.setCat(catArray[this.attributes['data-catarray-idx'].value])
  console.log("clicked on " + catView.selectedCat.name);
  catClicks.get(catView.selectedCat).clicks++
}

var catViewId=0
var p=CatView.prototype
p.setCat=function(cat){
this.selectedCat=cat
this.update()
return this
}
p.appendToElement = function(element){
  element.appendChild(this.catView)
  return this
}
p.template= (name,photoURL) =>
  `<img src="${photoURL}" height=100 width=100><span>${name}</span>`
p.update=function(){
  this.catView.innerHTML = 
  this.template(
  this.selectedCat.name, this.selectedCat.url
  )
  return this
}
p.toString=function(){this.selectedCat.name + 'view'}
function CatView(){
  var me,cv,id
  id = 'catView'+catViewId++
  me = Object.create(CatView.prototype)
  cv = me.catView = document.createElement('div')
  cv.id = id;
  return me
}
whenReady()
```